# Detecting a keypress within a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a web page detect user keypresses within a particular form (there is a function to be called on each keypress). However my code is not working (console never prints to the log):

```
$(document).on("keypress","filterinput",function(e) {
    console.log("press detected");
});

<form class="filterform"><input class="filterinput" type="text"></form>
```

Comment: Change `filterinput` to `.filterinput`. Also, unless your form is being dynamically generated, you shouldn't have to use the event delegation syntax.

Comment: @Blender - ...or if there are many forms like this, and it's just better to have one event handler...

Comment: From the JQuery docs:

**Note:** as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

You may want to look at keyup() or keydown()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.` in the class selector:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".filterinput", function(e) {
//                          ^ this . indicates that it's a class selector
    console.log("press detected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your selector should be `.filterinput`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the period `.` in your selector that signifies "look for a class":

```
$(document).on("keypress",".filterinput",function(e) {
//                         ^ period
```

Comment: CSS classes are applied to HTML elements to identify them for styling or programming purposes.  CSS class syntax is ".[className]"  His JavaScript did not work because he did not supply it with the CSS class name correctly.  You write in your answer that the dot is an operator that does something programmatically, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".filterinput").keypress(function(e)
    {
        console.log("press detected");
    });

    <form class="filterform"><input class="filterinput" type="text"></form>
```